# Determine total number of bytes read by a process

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

I am currently working on a project where one of our goals is to reduce the total amount of data read from disk. Is there a way to determine the total number of bytes run by a process? I am working with on a C++ application built with Visual Studio 2005, running on Windows XP.

Ideally, I would like some sort of monitor that can print results if I specify a process name. But, if there's some sort of API I can use in my own application, that would be good too.

I know that this must be possible somehow, because I can display the total number of bytes read in the task manager as the process is running, I would like to be able to obtain this number for a process that has already finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GetProcessIOCounters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683218(VS.85).aspx) function.  This returns total read operations, write operations, other, read bytes, write bytes, and other bytes.  The process still needs to be alive for this to work - holding a handle to the process should be sufficient.  Alternatively, your process could log this info on exit.

If your goal is to reduce your disk I/O, I recommend you use the Windows [Performance Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx).  This will show you what files you are reading the most data from, which threads are reading the most data, and help give you a bit more of a system wide view as well, in case you are causing disk I/O elsewhere in the system.

Comment: The Windows Performance Toolkit looks great, unfortunately, it requires windows vista, and I am still on XP

Answer (score 0):

SysInternals's [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) will give you all I/O's of a process, including call stack. Their FileMon tool might be useful too.

Comment: ...and if you just want the high-level counts, in-box taskmgr.exe does the job too :)  Just make sure to show additional (optional) columns and select the appropriate fields for read I/O requests.

Comment: @Reuben - thanks, if you'll notice, I mentioned that in the question, but I want to be able to know without having to watch the task manager, and I want something that will persist.